# how can I make just the Form background transparent but not other controls

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

Say I want to make just the very background of windows form transparent but keep the buttons and the groupboxes 100% NOT transparent and visible. Is there an easy way to do that?? thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From form properties `TransparencyKey` choose a color.
This color will be transparent so choose a rare color that is not used from your controls.
Then choose the same color for your form `BackColor`.

valter

Comment: Hi grant - yes...changing the opacity makes the forms transparent but the buttons turn into "barely visible". I want to make the buttons 100% visible and just the back glass effect. According to other users Windows 8 messes things even further (currently using win8). Anyway this is my progress that far and for now it works:

Comment: @valter: sorry missed your answer - yes this seems to be the easiest way IMO it seems. Just need to play with the buttons now for another 5 minutes to see if i can make them stand out with solid background.

Comment: Done. Once again though - future users may take a look here - pretty straight forward. here's my additional input: When you play with the buttons make sure the buttons have some color and are NOt transparent otherwise it's annoying for the users. Not the best approach though as the user can click "accross" the form. So if you have icons behind the form and the user misclicks with 0.1" right say the button won't be clicked. but it still looks fancy!