# Transparent Control, Transparent PictureBox background, but PictureBox Showing Black Background

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm creating a launcher for a game I'm working on.

I don't want the square edges of the Control, so I decided to try the route in making the control transparent, and having the `PictureBox` image I created as what you will mainly see as the background of the App itself.

I have the Control Transparency working, however, even though I've set the `PictureBox.BackColor` to `Transparent`, it still shows a Black background.

Basically, I just wanted my launcher to look a little "3d" with the logo and the edges coming out a little bit.  So the control is technically larger than the picturebox to make room for parts coming out a bit.

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Can you provide an image how it should be like and the code you trying achieve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22631203/how-can-i-make-just-the-form-background-transparent-but-not-other-controls

Comment: The image you use should contain a transparent canvas behind. Otherwise it displays a black back color

Comment: In Winforms there is not __real__ but only __faked Transparency__. It will work __if and only if__ the control is __nested__ in another control.  It will __not__ work between __overlapping controls__. There is basically no way around this. - Also noteworthy: you can __nest__ controls in `PictureBoxes` only using __code__, as it isn't a container. `pictureBox2.Parent = pictureBox1;`

Comment: Don't use a picture box. Override the `OnPaint` method of the form and paint the picture there using `Graphics.DrawImage`.